# update data in Mongo DB even when collection does not exist using node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I need to update a field which exists or not: I've tried this

```
db.foo.update(
    { site: '"wisdom'},
    { $set: {'club': 'fc barcelona'}}, (upsert=true)
)
```

Comment: So you want to update a field which might exist in the document or might not exist, and want to know if there would be a problem if the field does not exist, correct?

Comment: yes I just want to update or rather insert data if the field is there or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use upsert:true option of mongodb.
Basically it updates a document if the query string matches the document or if it is not 
matched then basically creates it. By default it's value is set to false.

```
db.foo.update(
  { site_id: "xxx" },
  { $set: { "title.de": "", "content.de": "" } },
  {upsert: true}
);
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/